# ufw firewall (command line and GUI) for elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, firewall

How to configure Firewall Configuration for elementary OS in non-GUI and GUI ?

Is there any GUI ufw available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By default `ufw` (Uncomplicated Firewall) installed in elementary OS.

  To `enable` open terminal and run the following command:

  ```
  sudo ufw enable
  ```

  To verify `status` :

  ```
  sudo ufw status
  ```

  For more information about `ufw`:

  ```
  man ufw
  ```
- There is a default GUI firewall in elementary OS,refer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/ufw-firewall-command-line-and-gui-for-elementary-os/2429#2429) .

  `gufw` is GUI for `ufw`.

  To install open terminal and run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gufw
  ```

  [image: Imgur]

  [image: Imgur]

Answer (score 4):

Since version 0.3 elementary OS has it's own graphical configuration interface for `ufw`.
You can find it in *System Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall*:

[image: Firewall configuration]

So, there is no need anymore for installing `gufw`.

Comment: Is there any difference in default firewall and `gufw`?

Comment: No difference in behavior, just different interface.